# How to server one static file through app yaml

Tags: python, yaml

I tried the following but it gave an error

```
- url: /path/mypage.html
  static_files: static/path/mypage.html
```

I also tried

```
- url: /path/mypage.html
  static_files: static/path/mypage
```

The error says `Missing "upload" attribute for URL "/path/mypage.html"`

Then I tried adding the `upload` and still get an error

```
- url: /path/mypage.html
  static_files: static/path/mypage
  upload: /path/mypage.html

  - url: /path/mypage.html
    static_files: static/path/mypage.html
    upload: /path/mypage.html
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

if you only wanna serve static file you can use the static_dir tag

```
 - url: /stylesheets       <-- the url subdirectory
 static_dir: stylesheets   <-- folder with the static files 

 - url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))$
 static_files: static/\1
 upload: static/.*\.(gif|png|jpg)$
```

The upload section represents a filepath, not a URL.

in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers) says that this configuration it's equivalent

```
handlers:
   - url: /images
   static_dir: static/images

   - url: /images/(.*)
   static_files: static/images/\1
   upload: static/images/.*
```